# Image doesn't load inside a frame

Tags: forms, xamarin, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app where I load an Image inside a Frame on a ViewCell. On Windows Phone 8.1 the image doesn't show the first time the page is shown, but if I navigate to another page and then return, it loads. Android and iOS work fine.

The problem is the Frame, because if I set the Image as the ViewCell's Content, it loads normally.

```
View = new Frame { 
    Content = new Image {
        Source = "img.png"
    }
};
```

Debugging I found out that both the Width and Height of the Image are -1. MinimiumWidthRequest and MinimumHeightRequest have no effect. I also tried using the FFImageLoading library, to no avail.

I use the frame so I can put a black border on it using a custom renderer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackLayout instead of Frame:

```
View = new StackLayout { 
Children = new Image {
    Source = "img.png"
}};
```